# S3 Lambda trigger double invocation after exactly 10 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, eventtrigger

We are experiencing double Lambda invocations of Lambdas triggered by S3 ObjectCreated-Events. Those double invocations happen *exactly* 10 minutes after the first invocation, not 10 minutes after the first try is complete, but 10 minutes after the first invocation happened. The original invocation takes anything in the range between 0.1 to 5 seconds. No invocations results in errors, they all complete successfully.

We are aware of the fact that SQS for example does not guarantee exactly-once but at-least-once delivery of messages and we would accept some of the lambdas getting invoked a second time due to results of the distributed system underneath. A delay of 10 minutes however sounds very weird.

Of about 10k messages 100-200 result in double invocations.

The AWS Support basically says *"the 10 minute wait time is by design but we cannot tell you why"*, which is not at all helpful.

---

- Has anyone else experienced this behaviour before?
- How did you solve the issue or did you simply ignore it (which we could do)?
- One proposed solution is not to use direct S3-lambda-triggers, but let S3 put its event on SNS and subscribe a Lambda to that. Any experience with that approach?

---

*example log: two invocations, 10 minutes apart, same RequestId*

> START RequestId: f9b76436-1489-11e7-8586-33e40817cb02 Version: 13
>   2017-03-29 14:14:09  INFO ImageProcessingLambda:104 - handle 1 records

*and*

> START RequestId: f9b76436-1489-11e7-8586-33e40817cb02 Version: 13
>   2017-03-29 14:24:09  INFO ImageProcessingLambda:104 - handle 1 records

Comment: As you very well described in the question, "does not guarantee exactly-once but at-least-once delivery of messages", if this is not messing up functionality, your second solution is the best at this point. I don't think 3rd solution makes any difference because duplicate event will be submitted again to SNS, due to the subscription Lambda will simply execute. If you really need to avoid duplicate processing, may be you can cache "RequestIds" some where in ElasticCache or other system and add a check-in Lambda to make sure request was already processed or not.

Comment: *"The AWS Support basically says..."*  Instead of paraphrasing something that doesn't make sense to you... what did they actually say?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot "I cannot go into the details of how the S3 events are implemented behind the scenes, but the service is behaving as expected, and for S3 events the 10 minute delay is by design", is that more helpful??

Comment: @Nambari any kind of caching or logic inside the lambda to prevent double invocations is complete overkill. We can deal with double invocations in general no problem, note that out of the few million sqs messages we sent out by now no double delivery (if it at all happened) ever caused problems. The 10 minutes between the double invocations is a problem. We can change out application to be able to deal with messages that are delayed by ten minutes, but that does not feel right and it does not help in understanding what is going on here.

Comment: I see.  Thank you for the clarification.  This is indeed strange, but it does appear that you have correctly diagnosed a genuine double invocation.  In my environment, I use S3 > SNS > Lambda rather than S3 > Lambda, because (a) there are (or may be) future targets wanting the same S3 event (b) it felt more right somehow, and I wonder if this changes the dynamics.  My process is writes to a database and is thus stateful and idempotent, so a duplicate invocation really just verifies that the work has already been done.  But I'll check the logs, since I may have something interesting...or not.

Comment: You mentioned 10K messages... over what time interval? And, what's your average runtime?  Note that I'm certainly not suggesting that either of these factors would be a sufficient reason for this behavior to occur... but I'm curious whether this is an issue that's triggered by high concurrency.

Comment: @luk2302 - "but the service is behaving as expected" - are you paying for that support? I'm not satisfied with that answer, especially when it comes from someone who doesn't know how things are implemented behind the scenes.

I'll keep an eye on this post anyway, I'm interested in where it gets.

Comment: Moreover, and sorry for the double post, I'm wondering why you think that the 3rd option might help in any way? 

Does SNS help in de-dup?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it is highly concurrent, the average runtime is a couple of seconds, that results in a few hundreds to thousands of lambdas executing at the same time. The process is for image processing, the load is not distributed over the day but has a couple of peaks whenever a new batch of images is available. We are basically writing whatever the lambda sends out to a database as well, but we drop it after all images that came in together have been processed. The double invocations do not cause any broken data or something like that, but we pay for the extra runtime and it is not pretty.

Comment: @johni I am as unsatisfied as you with that answer. Yes, we are paying for the support, I will check in with our account manager since the "regular" support is apparently out of options. Wanted to post on SO anyway in case someone stumbled upon the issue themselves and to be able to post a solution when and if one is found. SNS does not help in de-dup, but maybe there is another AWS-managed service at work when hooking a lambda onto SNS instead of hooking it directly onto S3 - not sure. That was something the support suggested and apparently it is working for Michael.

Comment: I had a high throughout pipeline (few TBs/day) based on lambda (triggered by Kinesis). I used elasticcache (smallest VM) for all lambdas executing in order to de-dup. On peak times I had 1500 lambdas running concurrently having no issues at all accessing the cache. I'm not sure if that a real overkill as mentioned. It is not expensive yet requires you to hold your lambda in the same VPC, which in some cases might require you to setup an internet gateway and pay additional cost for each byte going out of the VPC. What is the expected volume?

Comment: @luk2302 I would argue with AWS support with the point "we pay for the extra runtime", it is their fault and they should be accountable for the money or give a solution. But appreciate your effort in posting here, would be useful for the future readers.

Comment: For the record: we wrote a workaround in our message consumer to discard the messages resulting of duplicate lambda invocations.

Comment: We also see this issue, for the record. About 100 every 5-10k

Comment: For the record: this just happened again in a new environment and without any concurrency, I uploaded a single S3 object and it was processed twice with the same behaviour as before, same RequestId, same S3 versionId, no exceptions during either run, pretty much 10 minutes apart

Comment: We also see this issue, but far more frequently (eg, 5 / 30). Just like you, our lambda function completes successfully, and then 10 minutes later exactly, the lambda function is triggered again, with the same RequestID. This happens when triggering events from SNS, and also when triggering events from SQS via a consumer lambda function that runs once per minute. In the second case, the logs confirm that the SQS message is only consumed once. Totally unclear why the lambda function is invoked a second time.

Comment: We also came across with the issue. I found about 1-5% of duplicated requests. I use SDK->SNS->Lambda and API Gateway->Lambda (asynchronous mode) and for both methods I found duplications. And of course there are no any errors = no reason to retry call. In case of API Gateway->Lambda (synchronous mode) I've not found any duplications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of rounds with the AWS support and others and a few isolated trial runs it seems like this is simply "by design". It is not clear *why*, but it simply happens. The problem is neither S3 nor SQS / SNS but simply the lambda invocation and how the lambda service dispatches the invocations to lambda instances.

The double invocations happen somewhere between 1% and 3% of all invocations, 10 minutes after the first invocation. Surprisingly there are even triple (and probably quadruple) invocations with a rate of powers of the base probability, so basically 0.09%, ... The triple invocations happened 20 minutes after the first one.

*If* you encounter this, you simply have to work around it using whatever you have access to. We for example now store the already processed entities in a Cassandra with a TTL of 1 hour and only responding to messages from the lambda if the entity has not been processed yet. The double and triple invocations all happen within this one hour timeframe.

Comment: I believe it is due to the distributed nature of AWS services. There is more then one server which contain SQS event and communication between servers take time, so one server may have it marked as deleted but it still exists on other servers as new. Thus yes, this behavior is by "design"

Comment: @MaxZoom it has nothing to do with SQS, the lambda service itself is the problem. We almost never get duplicate SQS messages in millions of cases. I am quite aware of the fact SQS guarentees "at-least-once" delivery, but even there the delay between two invocations is not 10!!! minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Not wanting to spin up a data store like Dynamo just to handle this, I did two things to solve our use case

- Write a lock file per function into S3 (which we were already using for this one) and check for its existence on function entry, aborting if present; for this function we only ever want one of it running at a time.  The lock file is removed before we call callback on error or success.
- Write a request time in the initial event payload and check the request time on function entry; if the request time is too old then abort.  We don't want Lambda retries on error unless they're done quickly, so this handles the case where a duplicate or retry is sent while another invocation of the same function is not already running (which would be stopped by the lock file) and also avoids the minimal overhead of the S3 requests for the lock file handling in this case.