# S3 triggers Lambda Function twice with unique request id

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I used s3 to trigger my lambda function every time I uploaded a file in s3 bucket, I've tested it and it works but I noticed that S3 is triggering my lambda function twice with unique request id, even if I removed the entire codes and just add console.info('something') it's still trigger twice so clearly it's not lambda making retries if there's error. I also set retry to 0.

1st request id : awsRequestId: '9f73e49f-6cc7-454e-a89f-7d88122a7166'
2nd request id : awsRequestId: '1c8572d5-61ee-4b0b-93d9-4f8a3dcd28bf'
here's my code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
region: process.env.region,
accessKeyId: process.env.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey
});
const axios = require('axios');
const csvtojson = require('csvtojson');
const _ = require('lodash');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const { normalizeAndHashData } = require('./hash');
    const params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', 'myKey'}
    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    const eventsJson = await csvtojson().fromString(data.Body.toString());
    
    
    const result1 = await axios.post(`https://myurl`, eventJson);
    if (result1) {
        const sampleDataToUpload = {id: 1, name: 'test'}
        const result2 = await axios.post(`https://myurl2`, sampleDataToUpload); 
   
    }
    return context.succeed()
};
```

Comment: What are your S3 even rules? Maybe you have duplicates?

Comment: @Marcin I already checked and there's no duplicate

Comment: It happens for every single file?

Comment: Does the log file indicate that the function completed successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [S3 Lambda trigger double invocation after exactly 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786225/s3-lambda-trigger-double-invocation-after-exactly-10-minutes)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but maybe can give you some more details / context. How much time passes between the two invocations?

Comment: @luk2302 exact same time

Comment: @Marcin yes, every single file

Comment: Then you have some duplication setup. That is not a result of S3 or lambda behaving weirdly but something within your infrastructure. What does the notification config look like on S3, what is triggered by that, what is triggered by that, what is triggered by *that*? Does the source system write a file twice, do you have versioning enabled, etc!?

Comment: okay here's the thing, I tried uploading file directly to s3 and it only triggered once, but when I used ftp server where I mount the s3 bucket it triggered twice

Comment: Ooh! You should avoid "mounting" an Amazon S3 bucket for Production systems. The software you are using to make the bucket appear as a drive has to do strange things to make it work and it can lead to problems at scale.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein what would you suggest as alternative for this?

Comment: The best option is to transfer directly to Amazon S3, either via web page upload, or by making an API call (or AWS CLI). If you need to use an FTP-like server, see [New – AWS Transfer for SFTP – Fully Managed SFTP Service for Amazon S3 | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-service-for-amazon-s3/).

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein i'm currently exploring AWS Transfer Family